# "Message":"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds

Tags: asp.net, json

I designed jqgrid to display data but while executing I am getting error;

"Message":"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.","StackTrace":"

when i execute the grid with minimum data it runs ...

I even tried changing web.conf by :

```
<scripting>
<webServices>
  <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
</webServices>
```

but error remained same..Below is my web.conf file ..

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/></assemblies></compilation>
    <!--
      The <authentication> section enables configuration 
      of the security authentication mode used by 
      ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
       The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
       of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
       during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
       it enables developers to configure html error pages 
       to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
       </customErrors>
    -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly this is the solution for your problem. 
Try to set the maxJsonLength on your code behind (on the fly):

```
public static string GetJSONString <T> (List<T> data)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, RecursionLimit = 100 };
    return serializer.Serialize(data);
}
```

Initialize MaxJsonLength property when you create the object.
If this solution not working, I think you should delimit your JSON string lenghth.
Hope this help.